# Error al pasar argumento entre Fragments en kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragment

tengo una aplicación que estoy tratando de hacer con Activities y con Fragments, para practicar, y a la hora de pasar de la pantalla principal a una secundaria, pasandole un argumento, me indica el siguiente error:

```
2023-01-19 09:51:57.572 2493-2493/com.example.digifragment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.digifragment, PID: 2493
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.digifragment.model.DigiDescriptions.hashCode(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.AbstractList.hashCode(AbstractList.java:567)
        at com.example.digifragment.model.Digi.hashCode(Unknown Source:81)
        at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.hashCode(NavBackStackEntry.kt:256)
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.linkChildToParent(NavController.kt:143)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack(NavController.kt:1918)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack$default(NavController.kt:1813)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1721)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1719)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$NavControllerNavigatorState.push(NavController.kt:287)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:198)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:164)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:260)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1719)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1545)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1472)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1930)
        at com.example.digifragment.view.MainFragment.onViewCreated$lambda$1(MainFragment.kt:65)
        at com.example.digifragment.view.MainFragment.$r8$lambda$JIufCQZhcPs2zDthJ7cav-3d1xg(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.digifragment.view.MainFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
2023-01-19 09:52:03.144 384-384/? E/BpTransactionCompletedListener: Failed to transact (-32)
2023-01-19 09:52:05.651 1401-1779/? E/cr_CronetUrlRequestContext: Exception in upload method
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.q.d: Error code: 656394 | null
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.c.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.common.w.a.bv.run(SourceFile:6)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.ab.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.w.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.k.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.r.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
2023-01-19 09:52:05.651 1401-1775/? E/cr_CronetUrlRequestContext: Exception in upload method
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.q.d: Error code: 656394 | null
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.c.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.common.w.a.bv.run(SourceFile:6)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.ab.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.w.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.k.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.r.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
2023-01-19 09:52:07.026 345-345/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
2023-01-19 09:52:21.106 1401-1775/? E/cr_CronetUrlRequestContext: Exception in upload method
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.q.d: Error code: 656394 | null
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.c.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.common.w.a.bv.run(SourceFile:6)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.ab.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.w.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.k.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.r.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
2023-01-19 09:52:21.141 1401-1775/? E/cr_CronetUrlRequestContext: Exception in upload method
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.q.d: Error code: 656394 | null
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.c.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.common.w.a.bv.run(SourceFile:6)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.ab.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.w.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.k.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.r.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
2023-01-19 09:52:27.738 4152-4152/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.pixel.exo.core.PersistentService has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.pixel.exo.core.PersistentService$1@d3a7c23 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.pixel.exo.core.PersistentService has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.pixel.exo.core.PersistentService$1@d3a7c23 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1934)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcherCommon(LoadedApk.java:1806)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1785)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1965)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1896)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:810)
        at com.google.pixel.exo.core.PersistentService.bindToWirecutter(PersistentService.java:131)
        at com.google.pixel.exo.core.PersistentService.onStartCommand(PersistentService.java:121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4639)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2091)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
2023-01-19 09:52:39.926 5847-5847/? E/id.gms.unstabl: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2023-01-19 09:52:40.940 4792-4902/? E/WakeLock: DG:service ** IS FORCE-RELEASED ON TIMEOUT **
2023-01-19 09:52:52.079 1401-1779/? E/cr_CronetUrlRequestContext: Exception in upload method
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.q.d: Error code: 656394 | null
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.c.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.common.w.a.bv.run(SourceFile:6)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.ab.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.w.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.k.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.r.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
2023-01-19 09:52:52.140 1401-1775/? E/cr_CronetUrlRequestContext: Exception in upload method
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.q.d: Error code: 656394 | null
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.c.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.n.fZ(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.common.w.a.bv.run(SourceFile:6)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.ab.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.w.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.k.a.k.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.r.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.n.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.d.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
2023-01-19 09:53:11.533 1401-1401/? E/A: onError
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.n: errorCode: 65561, engine: 2
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.di.a.e.a(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.n.gF(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.ce.g.a.f.f(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.k.a.g.d(SourceFile:21)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.k.a.g.jG(SourceFile:6)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.o.d(SourceFile:15)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.p.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.e.run(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ay.run(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ay.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.h.run(SourceFile:4)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.p: errorCode: 65586, engine: 2
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.n.gF(SourceFile:1) 
        at com.google.ce.g.a.f.f(SourceFile:2) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.k.a.g.d(SourceFile:21) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.k.a.g.jG(SourceFile:6) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.o.d(SourceFile:15) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.p.run(SourceFile:1) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.e.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ay.run(SourceFile:1) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ay.run(SourceFile:1) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.h.run(SourceFile:4) 
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.l: errorCode: 401, engine: 2
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.assistant.shared.m.h.a(SourceFile:5)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.producers.j.gX(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.k.a.g.d(SourceFile:15)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.k.a.g.jG(SourceFile:6) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.o.d(SourceFile:15) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.p.run(SourceFile:1) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.e.run(SourceFile:2) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ay.run(SourceFile:1) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ay.run(SourceFile:1) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.h.run(SourceFile:4)
```

El archivo de MainFragment al que hace referencia sería este:

```
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding
    private val digiViewModel: DigiViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var digimon: Digi

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = view.findNavController()

        digiViewModel.cargarDatos()

        digiViewModel.digiLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            binding.digiName.text = it.name
            binding.digimonImage.load(it.images[0].href)
            binding.digimonLevels.apply {
                adapter = LevelAdapter(it.levels)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
            }
            binding.digimonAttributes.apply{
                adapter = AttributeAdapter(it.attributes)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
            }
            binding.digimonTypes.apply{
                adapter = TypeAdapter(it.types)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
            }
            binding.digimonFields.apply {
                adapter = FieldAdapter(it.fields)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
                addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL))
            }
            digimon = digiViewModel.digiLiveData.value!!
        }

        binding.digimonImage.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDetailsFragment(digimon))
        }
    }
```

Y a la hora de hacer el gráfico de navegación le paso los argumentos de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada vez que doy click en el único evento que tiene el fragment me da un error. Según parece es un error en la lambda pero no entiendo el por qué.

Después de debuggear la aplicación, puedo decir que el objeto que paso por parámetro no es null, es el objeto que quiero concretamente, el navController tampoco es null. De hecho, el único problema que llegué a encontrar modificando la pasada de parámetros es que el MainFragmentDirections debe dar algún tipo de error que desconozco completamente, ya que el resto funciona bien.

Comment: En alguna parte de tu còdigo llamas .hashCode() ?

Comment: No, en ninguna.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso el error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
> java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference

se debe a que estas enviando un parámetro con valor null al Fragment, esto seguramente se produce en este listener.

Puedes validar para evitar este error, pero debes revisar porque no se obtiene la información para el objeto digi :

```
      binding.digimonImage.setOnClickListener {
                if(digi != null){
navController.navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToDetailsFragment(digimon))
               }else{
                    //No se obtuvo información para digi
               }
           }
```